# How do I return a not complete object?

Tags: c#, linq, list

My select statement does not return the entire Customer object, just the *utrustningNr* and *beskrivning*. How do i **return** it in a correct way without getting this error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<fjallvick.utrustning>`

```
public List<utrustning> searchEquipment(string equipmentNr)
{
    var queryEquipment = from utrustning in globalDBConnString.context.utrustnings
                         where utrustning.utrustningNr == equipmentNr
                         select (new { utrustning.utrustningNr, utrustning.beskrivning });

    return queryEquipment.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Replace the `new { ... }` with `new utrustning { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<utrustning> queryEquipment = from Utrustning in globalDBConnString.context.utrustnings
                               where Utrustning.utrustningNr == equipmentNr
                               select new utrustning { Utrustning.utrustningNr, Utrustning.beskrivning };

          return queryEquipment.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `select` clause is creating a new anonymous type for each item, instead of a new `utrustning`. You may well want something like:

```
var queryEquipment = from utrustning in globalDBConnString.context.utrustnings
                     where utrustning.utrustningNr == equipmentNr
                     select new utrustning { 
                        utrustningNr = utrustning.utrustningNr, 
                        beskrivning = utrustning.beskrivning
                     };
```

Alternatively, if `globalDBConnString.context.utrustnings` actually returns a sequence of `ustrustning` values already, you could just use:

```
return globalDBConnString.context.utrustnings
                         .Where(u => u.utrustningNr == equipmentNr)
                         .ToList();
```

If you *want* to only return two properties, you may well be best off creating a new type which only *has* those two properties - then change the return type of the method, and change the `select` clause to use that.

Side-note: your code would be easier to understand if you followed normal .NET naming conventions.

Comment: It's an honor to get a comment from you Jon Skeet, WOW, feels like I can die now! :O
What should I change the return type of the method to?

Right now I get the error 'System.NotSupportedException' and Explicit construction of entity type 'fjallvick.utrustning' in query is not allowed.

Comment: @SadjadJohansson: Well I've given you various different options depending on what you're trying to achieve - we still don't really know that. If you find that you get things not being supported by the LINQ provider, you may need to project into an anonymous type, then use `AsEnumerable()` to do the rest locally, then project the anonymous type into a different named type. Search for `AsEnumerable` on SO - there are lots of answers that use that technique. (I'm boarding a plane soon, so probably won't be able to help out any more on this question.)

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting a new anonymous type when you do this: `select (new { utrustning.utrustningNr, utrustning.beskrivning })`

You can select a specific type by doing something like this:

```
public List<utrustning> searchEquipment(string equipmentNr)
{
    var queryEquipment = from utrustning in globalDBConnString.context.utrustnings
                         where utrustning.utrustningNr == equipmentNr
                         select new utrustning 
                             { 
                                 utrustningNr = utrustning.utrustningNr, 
                                 utrustning.beskrivning);
                             };

    return queryEquipment.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this with the query you have written there... you are returning an anonymous object, which you will not be able to give a name to in your code.

Assuming that `utrustningNr` and `beskrivning' are both strings:

Change

```
select new { utrustning.utrustningNr, utrustning.beskrivning }
```

to:

```
select new Tuple<string, string>(utrustning.utrustningNr, utrustning.beskrivning);
```

Then your return type is

```
List<Tuple<string, string>>
```